# how to remove both duplicate entries in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am simply trying to remove both entries if one is duplicate...for example if the array is

(9,1,2,2,3,4)...I need to output (9,1,3,4)

Most of the pandas methods like drop_duplicates() keep either the top or bottom entry. My data has always double duplicates and even number of elements always!

So example (1,4,6,7,3,3,0,0) output should be 1,4,6,7

Answer (score 1):

```
import collections
a = (1,4,6,7,3,3,0,0)
a = [x for x,y in collections.Counter(a).items() if y == 1]
```

Comment: thanks a ton! it works....have been searching the pandas library in vane trying to modify drop_duplicates!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have tuples there not arrays (lists in python use `[]`). If you want to keep it as tuples you could do:

```
# if you need a new tuple
a = (1,4,6,7,3,3,0,0)
b = ()
for i in a:
  if a.count(i) == 1:
    b = b + (i,)
print b # (1, 4, 6, 7)
```

You could even do it in one line:

```
# if you want to replace the original tuple
a = tuple(i for i in a if a.count(i) == 1)
print a # (1, 4, 6, 7)
```